# haml by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to configure rails to use haml by default, i.e. when a scaffold is generated the according `scaffold_name/index.html.haml` is generated instead of `scaffold_name/index.html.erb`.

Similar to how you are able to add `config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass` to `config/application.rb` and have `scaffold_name.sass` generated by default.

Tried adding the following to `config/application.rb`

```
config.generators do |g| 
  g.template_engine :haml
end
```

but ened up with the following

```
$ rails generate scaffold foo name:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20120208152550_create_foos.rb
  create    app/models/foo.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/foo_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/foos.yml
   route  resources :foos
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/foos_controller.rb
   error    haml [not found]
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/foos_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/foos_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/foos_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/foos.js.coffee
  invoke    sass
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/foos.css.sass
  invoke  sass
  identical    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.sass
$ rails destroy scaffold foo                                                                                                                        
  invoke  active_record
  remove    db/migrate/20120208152550_create_foos.rb
  remove    app/models/foo.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/unit/foo_test.rb
  remove      test/fixtures/foos.yml
   route  resources :foos
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  remove    app/controllers/foos_controller.rb
   error    haml [not found]
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/functional/foos_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  remove      app/helpers/foos_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  remove        test/unit/helpers/foos_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  remove      app/assets/javascripts/foos.js.coffee
  invoke    sass
  remove      app/assets/stylesheets/foos.css.sass
  invoke  sass
```

I created a nice little bundle command to replace all erb with haml files following [this](http://screencasts.org/episodes/using-haml-with-rails-3) screencast but I'm still interested in making it default when the scaffold is created!  How do I make it so haml files (not erb!) are generated by default?

Comment: This is Rails. Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I use `gem 'haml-rails', '= 0.3.4'` in my gemfile. it automatically generates `*.html.haml` without any configuration.

Comment: Specifying a version constraint usually isn't needed for new projects unless you know of issues with the latest version.

Comment: Haml-rails version 0.4 is the last version to support Rails 3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485147/haml-rails-on-rails-4-0/37693041#37693041

Answer (score 17):

In your application config, try setting the following:

```rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :haml
end
```

Comment: That gives me `error haml [not found]`, haml-rails is definitely in the gem file and I think you are along the right lines but what is the proper template_engine to specify haml or how do I add support for this?

Comment: Try adding 'haml' gem also into your GemFile gem 'haml',            '~> 3.1.4'
gem 'haml-rails',         '0.3.4'

Answer (score 8):

if you have **gem 'haml-rails'** in your Gemfile it should create haml files by default instead of erb.

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty simple!

All you need to do is to add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
```

and then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

Found this to be the complete solution

Say if you have an Rails Engine project named `rails_address`

Add the haml config to **lib/rails_address/engine.rb**

```
module RailsAddress
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace RailsAddress

    config.generators do |g| 
      g.template_engine :haml
    end
  end
end
```

Added haml deps to **rails_address.gemspec**

```
...
  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.1.10"
  s.add_dependency 'haml', '~> 4.0.6'
  s.add_dependency 'haml-rails', '~> 0.9.0'
...
```

Lastly require the haml gems in **lib/rails_address.rb**

```
require "rails_address/engine"
require "haml"
require "haml-rails"

module RailsAddress
end
```

Execute a `bundle install` just incase you have not installed the haml gems yet.

Now when you generate via scaffold or controller you will create haml views.

ex.

```
$ rails g scaffold Address street:string city:string state:string zip_code:string
...
invoke    haml
exist      app/views/rails_address/addresses
create      app/views/rails_address/addresses/index.html.haml
create      app/views/rails_address/addresses/edit.html.haml
create      app/views/rails_address/addresses/show.html.haml
create      app/views/rails_address/addresses/new.html.haml
create      app/views/rails_address/addresses/_form.html.haml
...
```

Comment: Great, thanks, that solved my problem. Though, I think it worth mentioning that for me specifying `s.add_dependency 'haml'` in the rails_address.gemspec and `g.template_engine :haml` in the lib/rails_address/engine.rb files were enough to make it generate haml views. (using rails 5.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

The `haml [not found]` error is usually because the bundle is incomplete. Have you tried running `bundle update` and then rerunning the generator?

Comment: No the issue still persists. Tried `bundle update`, issue still persists.  Removed the `Gemfile.lock` and called `bundle install`, issue still persists.