# haml-rails on rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm wondering if anyone has run into any snags with the `haml-rails` gem in Rails 4.0. There is a [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=comments) that says there were some problems but there is not much more mention of this. The gem hosted on GitHub also doesn't explicitly mention support for Rails 4.0. So what's the status on this?

Comment: Rails 4.1.0rc1 was not able to find haml views in my application. I had to put `haml-rails` gem to global gem list in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using `haml-rails (0.4)` in a rails 4 project and everything is working

Comment: I can co-sign the success with `haml-rails (0.4)` in Rails 4 app.

Comment: I am using haml (4.0.5), haml-rails (0.4) but I have problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215111/undefined-local-variable-or-method-render-meta-data

Answer (score 5):

Haml 4.0.4 have release to support rails 4 application. You can use haml-rails. Now, it doesn't have problem. Include gem package in gem file

> `gem 'haml-rails'`

and bundle the project