# Template not found with HAML on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm going through the [Getting Started With Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for my fourth time and want to do it with HAML this time.

I found [haml-rails on rails 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485147/haml-rails-on-rails-4-0) and edited my Gemfile to read:

```
# Use HAML instead of ERB
gem 'haml-rails'
```

Did `Bundle Install` which didn't throw any errors. Then as per the [HAML instructions](http://haml.info/tutorial.html) changed my files to read:

> _form.html.haml
>   edit.html.haml
>   index.html.haml
>   new.html.haml
>   show.html.haml

When I load, `localhost:3000/blog` it throws up the missing template message:

> Missing template companies/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "F:/Rails/portal/app/views"

What else am I missing to get HAML working?

Comment: Did you restart your server? Any changes outside of `app/` and `config/routes.rb` require a restart, especially `Gemfile`.

Comment: @tadman ah that did it. Now I've got other errors but the HAML seems to be working. If you want to make that an answer I'll mark it correct when it lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Rails is generally pretty good about picking up on changes made to your application when in the `development` mode, any modifications to files outside of `app/` and `config/routes.rb` do require a restart.

If you're using the `rails server` method, stop and start that. If using a system like [Pow](http://pow.cx/) then `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

Alterations to `Gemfile` require an explicit restart as this might change something dramatic like the version of Rails used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard gem:

```
gem 'haml'
```

And then `bundle install`. I hope that works.
Try **Slim** as well. It uses even less code:

Haml: `%h1 Title`

Slim: `h1 Title`